# React query and optional chaining async await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-query, optional-chaining

I don't think I understand how optional chaining affects the async/await functions.

I have a simple function that returns the user from Firebase Auth.

```
export async function getCurrentUser() {
  const curUser = await projectAuth.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult();
  return curUser || null;
```

With this code, if currentUser is null, curUser becomes undefined so I return null because react queryKey can not work with undefined results.

The problem is that, even when there is a logged in user, untill I manually click "refetch" in
ReactQueryDevTools, the data will not appear in cache and, therefore, will not appear in the UI.
In other words, on page reload, there is no user in cache untill I refetch the data.

Why is that?

When I don`t use optional chaining, I dont need to manually refetch to see the user in cache - I can see the returned curUser.

But in this case, without optional chaining, I have error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getIdTokenResult')

Here is the react query hook:

```
export function useCurrentUser() {
  const { isLoading, data: user } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["user"],
    queryFn: getCurrentUser,
    onError: (err) => console.log(err),
  });

  return { isLoading, user };
}
```

The reason why I know for sure that there is a logged in User is because when I try to get the user directly from the components, skipping the React Query step, I`m able to see the user.

So I'm not sure why I have to refetch the data manually with optional chaining or how to get rid of the type error if I dont user optional chaining.

Answer (score 0):

This has not so much to do with optional chaining as it has with `useQuery`s cache mechanism.

The reason for this is that on first render `projectAuth.currentUser === undefined`. So `useQuery` persist the value `null` in the cache, and depending on your `cacheTime` and `staleTime` settings it will remain there and be returned on every render.

What you want to do is inform `useQuery` once `projectAuth.currentUser !== undefined` to trigger a new fetch. This is done by updating the `queryKey`.

Update to

```js
queryKey: ["user", projectAuth.currentUser?.possiblySomePropertyToMakeThisAPrimitiveType]
```

and now `useQuery` will refetch as soon as `currentUser` is in place.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I updated the queryKey to include currentUsers email, but the issue persists: on the first page load, it is null until I manually refetch it...